# ./configure: C compiler cc is not found

Tags: server, compiling, nginx

I am currently trying to compile Nginx from source with the RTMP module on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS. Everything is ready and in place, but I can't compile. I get the following error:

```
./configure: error: C compiler cc is not found

debian/rules:150: recipe for target 'config.arch.full' failed
make[1]: *** [config.arch.full] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sysadmin/nginx/nginx-1.10.1'
debian/rules:126: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

I have already tried the following solutions:

- Installing `build-essentials`.
- Checking that `gcc` and `cc` are in `$PATH` and working.
- Trying `CC=/usr/bin/cc ./configure`, which gives the error:

  ```
  ./configure: error: C compiler /usr/bin/cc is not found
  ```
- Rebooting the system.

Comment: Isn't the compiler at /usr/bin/cc - maybe your path to the compiler is incorrect. What does `which cc` show?

Comment: I actually made an error in my question. I tried `/usr/bin/cc`, which gives the same error. `which cc` shows `/usr/bin/cc`.

Comment: It may be noteworthy that `/tmp` exists, but does not appear in `/etc/fstab`. Attempting to remount it with `sudo mount -o remount,rw,exec,nosuid /tmp` returns `mount: /tmp not mounted or bad option`.

Comment: Could check `ls -al /usr/bin/cc`? Your situation is quite strange.
I don't have enough reputation, so that I cannot add a comment. If I met your situation, I would check with 'ls -al' and then, `cd /usr/bin/` and run it with `./cc --version`.

Comment: Have you tried to compile and execute something basic to test your system and see if you get the same errors?  https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gcc-the-c-compiler-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa-linux  There is a simple sample file in item 3 of the link.

Comment: I also found this command in another question `make CC=gcc`  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095168/command-not-found-cc-make-error-127#1095184   It seems that you did something different and I am not sure if that will help or not.